# Integrating $\frac{1}{z^4}$ over the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to integrate

$$\int_{\vert z \vert = 1} \frac{1}{z^4}dz$$

I appeal to

$$\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))d\gamma(t)$$

And I get

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{e^{4 i t}} ie^{it}dt$$

this equals

$$i\int_0^{2 \pi}e^{-3 i t} dt=-\frac{1}{3}(e^{-3 i t})\bigg\vert_0^{2 \pi}=0$$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Yep that's right

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai sweet, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's perfect. Another way to solve it that can be useful for complicated integrals is the residue theorem. Since the only pole of the function inside your contour is at $z=0$, and $Res(f,0)=0$, we get that
$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z^4}dz=2\pi i Res(f,0)=0$$

Comment: Av even simpler  way is to realize that $\frac 1 {z^{4}}$ is a derivative. In fact the integral of $\frac 1 {z^{n}}$ is $0$ for all $n \neq 1$.

Comment: I like this way.   The Laurent series is right in front of you, and you can see that the residue is zero.